# How to cut year and month from file name

Tags: shell, unix

How to cut the Year and Month from file name like `ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09`

and take the value in 2 variables like:

```
ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09

year=2016
Month = 09
```

Answer (score 4):

**In Bash**

```
filename='ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09'
month="${filename: -2}"
year="${filename: -7:4}"

printf "year: %s\nmonth: %s\n" "$year" "$month"
```

*Output*

```
year: 2016
month: 09
```

**Portable version**

```
year="${filename%*_*}"
year="${year##*_}"
month="${filename##*_}"

printf "year: %s\nmonth: %s\n" "$year" "$month"
```

**P.S.**

In comments to another answer, you have mentioned that you actually have a filename with `.txt` extension. Extension can be cut off using `basename` command:

```
filename=$(basename "$filename")
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done portably with a suitable *internal field separator* (IFS) and `set`:

```
$ saved_IFS=$IFS
$ filename='ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09.txt'
$ IFS=_.
$ set -- $filename
$ echo $1
ABC
$ echo $2
PQRS
$ echo $3
XYZ
$ echo $4
2016
$ echo $5
09
$ echo $6
txt
$ IFS=$saved_IFS
```

Note how this is pure shell code. No bashisms and no expensive forks to awk, cut, basename or other.

Answer (score 1):

```
month=$(echo ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09.txt |awk -F_ '{split($NF,a,".");print a[1]}')
year=$(echo ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09.txt |awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1)}')

echo $month
09
echo $year
2016
```

OR

```
month=$(echo ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09.txt |grep -oP '_\K..(?=\.)')

year=$(echo ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09.txt |grep -oP '_\K\d{4}(?=_)')

echo $month
09
echo $year
2016
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my file is having extention .txt

Comment: month=$(echo ABC_PQRS_XYZ_2016_09.txt |awk -F_ '{print $(NF)}')

Comment: it's giving 09.txt